# Fix broken txt files from GREP reports

Tags: excel, text, grep, notepad++, preprocessor

I get a report from the companies servers (of which I have no control) in the form of grep txt dumps. I need to process them to get the info in a sane manner, which I use excel, and it works great.

Problem is, sometimes there are a few txt files that are broken, and cannot be processed with excel. Funny thing is, if I open them in notepad or something, copy all the data, create a new txt file, paste it all and there and process the new file, it works perfectly. Another curious thing is that when I do this, the new file which works, is a few kb's larger than the "broken" original.

My question is, is there a program, script or macro that I could use to

1. Open the text files in a folder
2. Copy the text of a file
3. Paste it in a new text file
4. Save that file with the same name as the original, in a different
   folder
5. Rinse and repeat for each file in a folder

Any idea is a great help, I have thousands of files to sift through each month, and it really is quite a pain.

Comment: This sounds like a text-encoding issue. Have you tried playing with the text-encoding settings in the Excel import?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: It's been a while since I used Excel (these days, I use OpenOffice), but I thought that when you import a csv, excel presents you with a dialog box with various options (separators, quotes, etc.), one of which is the text encoding.

Comment: you ran me down the right thought path. Turns out the files that were causing problems were Unix text files, not in the dos/windows format. I got todos.exe to batch convert the offending files to windows and it works 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the files were in Unix format rather than windows one. I ran todos.exe and it fixed my problems.